# Grub install fails on Fresh 18.04 alternate server Raid 1 installation

Tags: grub2, system-installation, raid, 18.04

I cant install Grub on a Fresh 18.04 alternate server Raid 1 installation.

I already tryed it 2 times and grub cant be installed, no matter which volume i try.

I use 2 physical volumes 4TB for Raid 1 and i created /boot /swap and /home INTO the Raid 1.
The raid 1 volume is using all space because i want it mirrored complete....

Comment: Is there an error message when you run `sudo grub-install /dev/<your-device>`?

Answer (score 1):

Its solved. I needed to set up a little 100MB grub-bios partition by installing on both drives.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)